# Electric Heater

Tags: heater

I'am installing a 240v heater which has a built in thermostat.I am hanging it from the garage ceiling.To adjust the thermostat you either have to be 8' tall, or use a ladder every time you change the heat setting. So I got a 240v line thermostat to mount on the wall. My question is, can you run 2 thermostats together? The heater has a fan delay, to stay running when the heater shuts off to cool the heating element. Can I turn the heater thermostat all the way up, and control the heater with the wall thermostat?

Comment: You might loose the fan delay since you're going to use a line thermostat. Depends on the wiring.

Comment: I am surprised it does not have a remote control like a cheap room AC unit.

Comment: It could be that the fan delay is not time-based but rather has it's own thermostat or thermocouple on/near the heating element. In which case, you idea should work fine. But, you'd need the schematics of the heater or a visual confirmation of a thermocouple controlling the fan to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know the model you have but I do this in my plant all the time, the ones I use the fan is on a thermal snap switch so it doesn’t matter if the heater is calling for heat or not. I bypass the OEM stat as the ones I have purchased that stat fails in a year and a half anyway. I have a 1/2 dozen running on line voltage cadet thermostats works great for our small shipping container shops.

Comment: I installed three Cadet line voltage thermostats in a steel heat treating factory. Worked great and saved finding a ladder each time to change settings.

Answer (score 0):

Because the heater wants to run the fan after the set temp is reached, you should do the following (we will assume celsius temp, since there is no location for the OP).

Set the heater thermostat to 20°. Set wall thermostat to off, heater does not come on. Set wall thermostat to 25°, heater comes on, heats to 20°, heater shuts off, fan continues to cool heater. If temp drops below 20°, heater comes on, etc. When no longer need heater, turn wall thermometer back to off when heater is not on.